# Detect when JFileChooser has been closed

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

[`JFileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) has a method [`addActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#addActionListener-java.awt.event.ActionListener-) which accepts an [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) which is invoked when the user presses one of the two buttons at the bottom of the `JFileChooser` window. But, as I discovered, it is not invoked when the user closes the `JFileChooser` by clicking on the close button in the window title bar of the chooser (or using an other method of the OS to close it). So my question is: How can a creator of a `JFileChooser` recognize when it has been closed in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JFileChooser` extends [`JComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html). So if you want to use it asynchronously instead of invoking `showDialog` and letting the rest of the UI freeze, you can embed the `JFileChooser` in a regular `JFrame` or any other [`Component`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) as it is done [here](http://www2.sys-con.com/ITSG/virtualcd/Java/archives/0507/hill/index.html).

Then you can listen for the close event of your `JFrame`. Little demonstration:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Select file");
            frame.setSize(400, 300);
            // disable default close behaviour of JFrame
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            frame.add(chooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            // little helper to close the JFrame properly
            Runnable closeFrame = () -> {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.dispose();
            };

            chooser.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                if (e.getActionCommand() ==
                        JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION) {
                    closeFrame.run();
                    System.out.println("User pressed approve button.");
                    File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                } else if (e.getActionCommand() ==
                        JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION) {
                    closeFrame.run();
                    System.out.println("User pressed cancel button.");
                }
            });

            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    // You could tell the user here
                    // that he has to select a file…
                    closeFrame.run();
                    System.out.println("User closed JFrame.");
                }
            });

            frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean like that:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    // select file      
} else if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
    // file chooser closed
}
```

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that JFileChooser.showDialog has a return value. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In conjunction with the result returned by [`showOpenDialog()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showOpenDialog-java.awt.Component-), you can add an [`AncestorListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/AncestorListener.html) and implement `ancestorRemoved()`.

Code:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.addAncestorListener(new AncestorListener() {

    @Override
    public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent e) {}
});
```

Console:

```
javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent[] on javax.swing.JFileChooser[…]
```